# Reverse Polish Notation evaluator in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, math-expression-eval

I've created an RPN evaluator in Haskell, as an exercise because I'm new to this language.

It runs well:

```
$ ./rpn 
2 3 4 5 + - +
-4
```

And the source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.String
import System.IO

data Token = TNum Int | TOp Operator
data Operator = Add | Sub | Mul | Div

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let tokens      = tokenise line
        (numc, opc) = countTok tokens
        !junk       =
            if numc == opc + 1
                then ()
                else error "Not a correct expression."
    print $ eval [] tokens


tokenise :: String -> [Token]
tokenise = map str2tok . words

eval :: [Int] -> [Token] -> Int
eval (s:_) []                   = s
eval stack (TNum t:ts)          = eval (t : stack) ts
eval (x:y:stacknoxy) (TOp t:ts) = eval (applyOp t y x : stacknoxy) ts

str2tok :: String -> Token
str2tok tkn@(c:_)
    | c `elem` ['0'..'9'] = TNum (read tkn :: Int)
    | otherwise = TOp $ case tkn of
        "+" -> Add
        "-" -> Sub
        "*" -> Mul
        "/" -> Div
        _   -> error $ "No such operator " ++ tkn

applyOp :: Operator -> Int -> Int -> Int
applyOp Add a b = a + b
applyOp Sub a b = a - b
applyOp Mul a b = a * b
applyOp Div a b = a `div` b

countTok :: [Token] -> (Int, Int)
countTok [] = (0, 0)
countTok (t:ts) =
    let (x, y) = case t of
            TNum _ -> (1, 0)
            _      -> (0, 1)
     in (x, y) `addPair` countTok ts

addPair :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> (a, b)
addPair (x, y) (z, w) = (x + z, y + w)
```

How can this code be improved? I hope my implementation is elegant, and if it isn't - what are the ways to clean it up?  In particular, I really don't like the `error`s because they're just ugly:

```
./rpn
5 6 + +
rpn: Not a correct expression.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at rpn.hs:16:22 in main:Main
```

I know they can be replaced with `fail`, which has a much nicer output, but from what I've read it can only be done inside a function that returns `IO ()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would convert all of the functions which might throw an error to return some kind of failable type, like `Maybe Int` or `Either String Token`. This includes `str2tok`, `tokenize`, and `eval`. This would also remove the need for the `countTok` function, since the program can just return an error value from `eval` instead. With the help of the `Monad` instances for these error types, this is a relatively simple change.

Next, I would use [`isDigit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) from `Data.Char` instead of `` c `elem` ['0'..'9'] `` because `isDigit` makes less comparisons in order to determine if it's a digit.

Lastly, I would change the `Operator` type to the function type `Int -> Int -> Int`. This will remove the need for `applyOp` and will consolidate all the places that would be necessary to change if you wanted to extend the program to accept more operators.

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

data Token = TNum Int | TOp (Int -> Int -> Int)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    either putStrLn print $ do
        tokens <- tokenize line
        eval [] tokens

tokenize :: String -> Either String [Token]
tokenize = mapM str2tok . words

str2tok :: String -> Either String Token
str2tok tkn
    | (c:_) <- tkn, isDigit c = Right $ TNum (read tkn)
    | otherwise = TOp <$> case tkn of
        "+" -> Right (+)
        "-" -> Right (-)
        "*" -> Right (*)
        "/" -> Right div
        _   -> Left $ "No such operator " ++ tkn

eval :: [Int] -> [Token] -> Either String Int
eval (s:_) []                   = Right s
eval stack (TNum t:ts)          = eval (t : stack) ts
eval (x:y:stacknoxy) (TOp t:ts) = eval (t y x : stacknoxy) ts
eval _ _                        = Left "Not a correct expression."
```

Comment: Brilliant! But I have one more question, what does the `<$>` do? I suspect it has to do something to do with Monads, which I don't grasp, unfortunately.

Comment: `<$>` is the infix operator alias for `fmap`. If it's easier for you to read, you could use `fmap TOp $` instead of `TOp <$>`